# Simple Form Collection - drop down menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using Simple Form in my rails app.

I have a form to create a profile where users select their universities. Profiles belong to Universities.

```
 <%= f.association :university, collection: University.all(id: 'name'), prompt: "Choose your university" %>
```

My db has a list of 10 universities in it, they are stored with the attribute: 'name' in the Universities table.

I'm trying to make a drop down list in the profile create form which has a list of those 10 univerisites. I've tried the above association. I get an error which says:  Unknown key: id

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Try `<%= f.collection_select :university, University.all, :id, :name %>`

Comment: Thanks. That worked but now the show isn't picking up the logo of the university (which previously worked)

Comment: That will be some other issue, can you please post ur `show` code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311661/rails-carrierwave-and-simple-form

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

`collection: University.all.map {|u| [u.name, u.id]}`

Comment: Hi Vineeth - I tried that but I get this error: undefined method `collection' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x00000103b1ff90>