# Rails Carrierwave and Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, simple-form

I have a rails 4 app that I use with simple form and carrierwave.

In my profile view, I have a form that includes a request for users to nominate their university, as follows:

```
<%= f.collection_select :university, University.all, :id, :name %>
```

In my university model, I create universities and add their associated logos:

{ :class => 'question-project' }, placeholder: 'Your uni name', :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 650px', class: 'response-project'} %>

```
  <%= f.label :'Your university logo', :label_html => { :class => 'question-project' }, placeholder: 'Insert JPG image', :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 650px', class: 'response-project'}%>

  <%= f.file_field :logo %>
```

I have an avatar_uploader which has a logo version to resize the image of the university logo. I call that version: logo.

I use that in my profile view to show the university and the university logo as follows:

```
            <%= image_tag (@profile.university.logo.logo) %>
```

The first logo is a reference to the logo in the university table and the second is to the name of the avatar uploader version.

I get an error when I test this that says:

```
undefined method `logo' for nil:NilClass
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Thank you

Comment: `@profile.university.logo` this is returning nil, see why it is nil?

Comment: Hi Sontya, how do i see why it is nil?

Comment: see why `logo` is not saving to `logo` field in unviversities table. @profile.university, try printing this value on console, and check it's logo field.

Comment: Thanks Sontya - I'll try to find instructions for how to do that

Comment: from your form `f.file_field :logo`, this will ask you for logo file selection, and when you submit form in params you can see 'logo' file name to be sent, that should be saved in logo field of universities table.

Comment: Thank you - I'm so stupid - I was missing = after <%. Thank you!